# How to wrap node js app into a rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I have a nodeJS app that does some calculations. I'm curious if there's a way(and makes sense) creating a rails gem for my app that'd run that nodeJS app and communicate with rails (I'm using heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running nodejs app as a separate app with a shared REDIS. I used REDIS subscribe (pub/sub) to communicate between rails app and nodejs up, and a constantly running rake task on rails side that'd create sidekiq jobs for messages from nodejs app.

However, it's as easy just to run nodejs app on a worker specifying it in the *Procfile*, like:

```
nodejs: node nodeapp/index.js
```